# Microsoft Excel Web App

Tags: javascript, excel, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out a way to embed the Microsoft excel web app in an iframe on my own webapp.  I like how the [Microsoft Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/) work and would love to be able to send some data from my webpage that I have stored in a javascript object over to this app.  Is there anyway that I can do that?  Right now the only way I can seem to get any data into this app is to create a file on a skydrive and then open it in the app, but what I really want to do is just have it open some data into some cells and then let the user do whatever they want with the data and save it on their computer or own skydrive.

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?  Sorry I don't have any code but I haven't tried anything yet because I really don't know where to start and can't find documentation on if it is possible to open this app with external data?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like you can create one. The only option for right now would be to upload a blank document and use that.

Take a look at http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/09/23/embedding-excel-web-app-in-your-own-web-page-or-blog.aspx

If that is not to your liking, you can always try [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) which has an extensive [API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make it editable but not able to save it?  So then I could have one blank file sitting out there and it doesn't matter how many people end up using it?

Comment: @M.Laing I just added a link to my answer. This one is editable, but not savable unless you open it in your "drive".

Comment: Cool that's getting closer to what I want... What I would really like is the following.  If you go to the link you gave, under the chart the very right button takes you to the excel web app.  Then you can click on edit in browser there.  I want to be able to embed the page that that button takes you to (the edit in browser) on my webpage... is that possible or is as close as I can get the excel mashup stuff? Thanks again!

Comment: @M.Laing, I also added a link to Google Docs which has an extensive API.

Comment: Yea I was thinking about just giving up with the microsoft web app and going to Google since it is better documented.  I'll keep messing with it for a little bit longer and switch to Google Docs if I can't get what I want.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As an advice to help you! You should to know any server side scripting language such as PHP. Excel files may be saved as csv -commas separated values- and those files could be manipulated easily using PHP or any other server side scripting technology.